# flutter check if string starts with RegExp

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

in flutter if we want to check if a string starts with a specific character...we can achieve that by:

```
var string = 'Dart';
string.startsWith('D');  // true
```

what if we want to check if the given string starts with multiple characters....i want to achieve this behaviour:

```
RegExp myRegExp = ('a-zA-Z0-9');
var string = 'Dart';
string.startsWith('D' + myRegExp);
```

is the above code is right?!!

my goal is to check if the string starts with a letter i specify...then a RegExp....
not to check if the string starts with 'D' only and thats it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what if we want to check if the given string starts with multiple characters....i want to achieve this behaviour:
>
> ```dart
> RegExp myRegExp = ('a-zA-Z0-9');
> var string = 'Dart';
> string.startsWith('D' + myRegExp);
> ```

That won't work. `'D'` is a `String` object, and `myRegExp` presumably is intended to be a `RegExp` object. (Your syntax isn't correct; you probably want `RegExp myRegExp = RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]');`.) Both `String` and `RegExp` derive from a [`Pattern` base class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Pattern-class.html), but `Pattern` does not provide `operator+`, and [`String.operator+`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/operator_plus.html) works only with other `String`s.  Conceptually it's unclear what adding a `String` and `RegExp` *should* do; return a `String`?  Return a `RegExp`?

You instead should just write a regular expression that accounts for your first character:

```dart
RegExp myRegExp = RegExp('D[a-zA-Z0-9]');
```

However, if you want the first character to be variable, then you can't bake it into the string literal used for the `RegExp`'s pattern.

You instead could match the two parts separately:

```dart
var prefix = 'D';
var restRegExp = RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]');

var string = 'Dart';
var startsWith =
  string.startsWith(prefix) &&
  string.substring(prefix.length).startsWith(restRegExp);
```

Alternatively you could build the regular expression dynamically:

```dart
var prefix = 'D';
var restPattern = r'[a-zA-Z0-9]';
// Escape the prefix in case it contains any special regular expression
// characters.  This is particularly important if the prefix comes from user
// input.
var myRegExp = RegExp(RegExp.escape(prefix) + restPattern);

var string = 'Dart';
var startsWith = string.startsWith(myRegExp);
```

Comment: thanks for your great explanations...many misconceptions have been resolved with this answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want something like `string.startsWith(RegExp('D' + '[a-zA-Z0-9]'))`;

Comment: Sounds promising....its too late here at night so i will try it at morning.....cant wait to give it a try...thanks for you reply.